# Django group by multiple column and get count of unique combination

Tags: django

In my model there are 10 fields, out of which below four I need to group on,

department
city
state
zip

And then get count of records which has same combination of these values

Example
IT|Portland|Oregon|11111 => 100

I tried annotate however it is not giving me desired results. Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

YourModel.objects.values('department', 'city', 'state', 'zip').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

Comment: You may also need to add an empty `order_by()` if there is a default Meta.ordering in this model

Comment: why is `'id'` used in the expression `Count('id')`? Where is `id` coming from and how does it relate to the combination of model values selected?

Comment: `id` is the default primary-key field in Django. Doing `Count('id')`, means do a count of all rows in that table, because every id is unique.

Comment: @user5359531 As far as I understand, the main reason this works is because of how `annotate()` works when preceded by `values()`; see [the Django docs on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#values).